# Rcpp error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp

I am using RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have created code for an R package using Rcpp.

My code worked fine until I moved it in to the R package. Now I am getting the error:

```
error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

The guilty line of code is:

```
typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<Random> > ears_t;
```

The top of my cpp file contains reference to the cpp11 plugin

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;
```

The description file links to and imports the various packages:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp, BH
Imports: Rcpp, BH, raster, XML
```

I have seen one post that suggests the problem relates to the non-inclusion of the memory class and another that relates to C++11.

Either way I am unsure how to solve the issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to have `SystemRequirements: C++11` at the end of your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: It is also good practice to accept an answer you are satisfied with so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 4):

For packages with C++11 you want to have the following in your `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
SystemRequirements: C++11
```

As suggested by Dirk another possibility is adding the following to a `src/Makevars{.win}` file:

```
CXX_STD=C++11
```

Comment: That is one of _several_ possibilities and my preference is to add `CXX_STD=C++11` to `src/Makevars{.win}` instead. YMMV.